# How to ssl-secure mysql connection on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, security, mysql, ssl, odbc

I use MS Access to connect my remote MySQL database, and use MySQL ODBC connector for that. I would like to secure the connection with SSL. ODBC connector offers some SSL setup, but I don't have idea what to fill in! When I connect from linux, I simply give `--ssl` option to `mysql` command, but what to fill in here?

I use Windows XP. Do I need to install something? Hopefully not... Also, what about newer Windows versions?

[image]

Comment: Your question was deleted automatically because it had low views and no positive score. I undeleted it for you—feel free to place a bounty on it.

Comment: @Thomas your question was undeleted before when you said you wanted to get more attention by putting a bounty on it, but you never did. If you still have this problem and want it solved, please place a bounty on it to get some attention. Otherwise it will be automatically deleted for inactivity again in the future.

Comment: @nhinkle but why should such questions be deleted? I have many thumbleweed questions around the SE but they never were deleted.

Comment: I have tumbleweed questions with even lower views on SO but they never got deleted.

Comment: @Thomas see the details here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/139837